# How to get max salary in each department wise with all the employee name

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMP 
(
    `EID` INTEGER,
    `ENAME` VARCHAR(30),
    `DEPT` VARCHAR(30),
    `SALARY` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO EMP (`EID`, `ENAME`, `DEPT`,`SALARY`)
VALUES (111, 'BABAUL', 'HR', 3000),
       (112, 'SILK', 'IT', 1000),
       (113, 'LEATHER', 'PAN', 4000),
       (221, 'COTTON', 'IT', 2000),
       (222, 'SILK', 'PAN', 5000),
       (223, 'LEATHER', 'HR', 6000),
       (224, 'LEATHER', 'ELEC', 1500);
```

Sample input

```
EID ENAME   DEPT    SALARY
--------------------------
111 BABAUL  HR      3000
112 SILK    IT      1000
113 LEATHER PAN     4000
221 COTTON  IT      2000
222 SILK    PAN     5000
223 LEATHER HR      6000
224 LEATHER ELEC    1500
```

Desired output

```
EID ENAME   DEPT    SALARY  MAX_salary
---------------------------------------
224 LEATHER ELEC    1500     1500
111 BABAUL  HR      3000     6000
223 LEATHER HR      6000     6000
112 SILK    IT      1000     2000
221 COTTON  IT      2000     2000
113 LEATHER PAN     4000     5000
222 SILK    PAN     5000     5000
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `WITH cte AS (SELECT dept, MAX( salary ) AS max_salary FROM emp GROUP BY dept ) SELECT * FROM emp INNER JOIN cte ON emp.salary = cte.max_salary AND cte.dept = emp.dept`

Comment: It's not giving the output as expected @Dai

Comment: I'm sure you're capable of editing the query I gave you to get the exact results you want.

Comment: Yes i tried but i am not getting the details of each employee as using group by it only gives the distinct of department , so i am facing the problem there ,i know how to calculate max salary but i am not getting the expected output , if you can just help me with that exact o/p.@Dai

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea for a query - why would you want the max-salary-per-department displayed like that?

Comment: It is a requirement @Dai .

Comment: Then _the requirements are wrong_. If you encounter bad project requirements then it's your duty as a software engineering professional to work with your boss/client towards a better spec - you should _not_ follow orders or requirements without-question (and without thinking...). That's a violation of engineering ethics.

Answer (score 0):

Tested, I got the same desired output:

```
SELECT E.EID, E.ENAME, E.DEPT, E.SALARY, 
(SELECT MAX(G.SALARY) FROM EMP G WHERE E.DEPT = G.DEPT GROUP BY G.DEPT) [MAX_SALARY] 
FROM EMP E
GROUP BY E.EID, E.ENAME, E.DEPT, E.SALARY 
ORDER BY E.DEPT
```

[image]

Comment: Please add some info on why you have `GROUP BY E.EID, E.ENAME, E.DEPT, E.SALARY ` I do think that it is not needed to `GROUP BY` here.

Comment: Based on your desired output you grouped the result query by EID, ENAME than DEPT, so I need to put every selected field into the `Group by` clause because `GROUP BY E.EID` alone will show you this error:
`Column 'EMP.ENAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` 

But you  can remove `GROUP BY E.EID, E.ENAME, E.DEPT, E.SALARY` if that order doesn't matter

Hope this is helping you

Comment: I am not the question asker, I am only commenting on your response!.......   The desired output only shows only something that is ordered, not grouped.

Comment: Thnxx @Luuk for the answer .

Answer (score 0):

You want a window function:

```
select emp.*,
       max(emp.salary) over (partition by emp.dept) as max_salary
from emp
order by emp.dept, emp.salary;
```